# Avalon Dock and Caliburn Micro - no title on document pane (tab header)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, avalondock

I am familiar with Caliburn Micro and the paradigms it uses, but am now trying to integrate AvalonDock.

As a POC, I have a very simple app with a shell view model containing a button which activates my StructureViewModels - a simple class containing a name and a title. The view for the structure is a user control which just displays the name as text.

The ViewModels and Views are hooking up nicely using Caliburn and they are being displayed in the Docking Manager. I can drag and detach, enumerate panes etc. - all the Avalon features seem to work. The problem I have is that they are displayed without the title in the Avalon Header (tab).

[image: Screenshot]

ShellViewModel:

```
using AvalonDemo.Properties;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace AvalonDemo.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
    {
        private int _structureCount;

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            WindowTitle = Resources.MainWindowTitle;
            _structureCount = 1;
        }

        public string WindowTitle { get; set; }

        public void OpenStructure()
        {
            ActivateItem(new StructureViewModel
            {
                Name = "Structure" + _structureCount++,
                Title = "Structure" + _structureCount
            });
        }
    }
}
```

***Edited with solution:***

ShellView:

```
<Window x:Class="AvalonDemo.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:avalonDock="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    xmlns:common="clr-namespace:AvalonDemo.Common"
    Title="{Binding WindowTitle}"
    Height="850" Width="1200">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Button x:Name="OpenStructure" Grid.Row="0" Width="50">Open</Button>

    <avalonDock:DockingManager
        Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DockingManager"
        DocumentsSource="{Binding Items}">

        <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutItem}">
                <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
            </Style>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>

        <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
            <common:AutobinderTemplateSelector>
                <common:AutobinderTemplateSelector.Template>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding . }" IsTabStop="False" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </common:AutobinderTemplateSelector.Template>
            </common:AutobinderTemplateSelector>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>

        <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
            <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                    <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane />
                </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
            </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
        </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>

    </avalonDock:DockingManager>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

StructureViewModel:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace AvalonDemo.ViewModels
{
    public class StructureViewModel : Screen
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

StructureView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AvalonDemo.Views.StructureView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Finally, I am using an Autobinder to select DataTemplates:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace AvalonDemo.Common
{
    public class AutobinderTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate Template { get; set; }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject  container)
        {
            return Template;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to limit code to the minimum just to get a POC working, but haven't seen many (any?) working examples using Caliburn to handle active VMs and Avalon Dock 2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited with solution, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh my, I spent ages trying things last night and as soon as I posted the question, I found the answer (StackOverflow-rubber duck?)

In the hope that this helps someone else, I just needed a LayoutItemContainerStyle adding to the shell view to tell Avalon where to get the Title from:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutItem}">
          <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
     </Style>
</avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
```